# How to set the mouse cursor to a specified location on a label?

Tags: vb6, mouse

so i have developed this game in visual basic 6.0,a maze game in which i want my mouse cursor to be set on the start label on the form with maze and once the form is activated and gets focus!

```
Dim label1 As New label=Start
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What form you are talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done similar tasks in the past using the Windows API.  In the following example, a Form contains a Label named 'Label1' that is positioned somewhere on the Form.  When the Form is Activated, the cursor will be centered on 'Label1':

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long

Private Type RECT
   Left As Long
   Top As Long
   Right As Long
   Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Dim wr As RECT
    Dim tb As Long
    Dim le As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    
    'calculate coordinates
    Call GetWindowRect(Me.hwnd, wr)                                    'window coordinates
    tb = (Me.Height - Me.ScaleHeight) - (Me.Width - Me.ScaleWidth) / 2 'title bar height
    le = (Me.Width - Me.ScaleWidth) * 0.5                              'left edge of client area
    
    'calculate center of label
    x = wr.Left + ScaleX(le + Label1.Left + Label1.Width * 0.5, Me.ScaleMode, vbPixels)
    y = wr.Top + ScaleY(tb + Label1.Top + Label1.Height * 0.5, Me.ScaleMode, vbPixels)
    SetCursorPos x, y
End Sub
```